# How to give tabs or indent to symbol representation

Tags: equations, symbols, split

I need to give indent or tab to each symbol I tried `\quad`, `\tab`, `\indent` but doesn't work.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
Where,\\
&$u_{i}=$ Horizontal displacement
&$v_{\mathrm{i}}=$ Vertical displacement\\
&$\varphi_{i}=$ Rotation Angle\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. Why do you use $ into an enviroment \equation that is already in math-mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this is it sufficient and is corresponds to your request?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext} % optional package for text font in Times New Roman
\begin{document}
Where,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
u_{i} &= \text{Horizontal displacement}\\
v_{i} & = \text{Vertical displacement}\\
\varphi_{i} & = \text{Rotation Angle}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext} % optional package for text font in Times New Roman
\usepackage{newtxmath} % optional package for math-font Times New Roman
\begin{document}
Where,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
u_{i} &= \text{Horizontal displacement}\\
v_{i} & = \text{Vertical displacement}\\
\varphi_{i} & = \text{Rotation Angle}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My guess is that equation numbering is not required...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Hi :-) Now I make an edit...I am a scarce user...especially for to understand the English language. :-)

Comment: These are typical notations that might *follow* a numbered equation containing the cited symbols, given for clarity.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you for your valuable reply. Can you please tell me how to change the horizontal distance of &. Means how can i define the spacing of &?

Comment: @Vedang The spacing of the & it is definited by array like the answer of Mico. I suggest to ask another question :-) on this theme. Welcome in TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that employs an `array` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}            % for \newcolumntype macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}  % (cancel) automatic math mode

\begin{document}
\noindent
Where,\\
\hspace*{1.5cm}%
$\begin{array}{@{} r @{{}={}} L @{}} % 1st col. in math mode, 2nd col. in text mode
  u_{i}          & Horizontal displacement \\
  v_{\mathrm{i}} & Vertical displacement\\ % why '\mathrm{i}' ??
  \varphi_{i}    & Rotation Angle 
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your precious time and reply. As you asked the question about why \mathrm{i}. I used one software to translate it but it translated the equation in an unusual way. But your solution helped me to define custom horizontal space. Thank you :)

Comment: @Vedang - You're most welcome.